# ansible unarchive using creates not working as expected

Tags: ansible

Here is my task. It basically unarchives a file into the dest directory /usr/local/hadoop.

The hadoop folder is not there and I get this error -

Error:-

```
fatal: [default]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "dest 'dest=/usr/local/ creates=/usr/local/hadoop copy=no' must be an existing dir"}





- name: Unarchive a file 
  unarchive:
    src: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz
    dest: dest=/usr/local/ creates=/usr/local/hadoop copy=no
    remote_src: yes
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some syntax issues with your task.  You can't combine legacy `key=value` syntax with YAML syntax.  In particular, this line...

```
dest: dest=/usr/local/ creates=/usr/local/hadoop copy=no
```

...is just passing a really long string to the `dest` key.  You want:

```
- name: Unarchive a file 
  unarchive:
    src: /home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz
    dest: /usr/local/ 
    creates: /usr/local/hadoop
    copy: no
    remote_src: yes
```

Comment: Thanks it worked. After changing it, the files are extracted and copied into the folder hadoop-2.7.1 and not hadoop. Should'nt it create the folder 'hadoop' and extract it.

Comment: It will simply unarchive the contents of `/home/hduser/hadoop-2.7.1.tar.gz`. If that contains a `hadoop-2.7.1`, that's what you're going to get.